# Why is maskedEditExtender not replacing the mask?

Tags: asp.net, input, mask, maskededitextender

I have a simple time box that seems like it should work but has a couple issues:

1. The cursor jumps to the end of the input
2. The mask "_" is not being replaced as the user types

   ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender 
   ID="meeStartTime" 
   runat="server"
   TargetControlID="txtStartTime"
   Mask="99:99"
   MessageValidatorTip="true"
   OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus"
   OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError"
   MaskType="Time"
   DisplayMoney="None"
   AcceptNegative="None"
   AcceptAMPM="true"
   ErrorTooltipEnabled="True"

   ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator ID="mevStartTime" runat="server"
   ControlExtender="meeStartTime"
   ControlToValidate="txtStartTime"
   EmptyValueMessage="Enter a Start Time"
   InvalidValueMessage="Start Time is invalid"
   Display="Dynamic"
   TooltipMessage="Input a Start Time"
   EmptyValueBlurredText="*"
   InvalidValueBlurredMessage="*"
   IsValidEmpty="false"

I can't quite see any errors in the code but I may be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Add two more attributes to MaskedEditExtender tag:

```
InputDirection="LeftToRight" 
ClearMaskOnLostFocus="True"
```